# Output of different time back-calculations without a change once displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I want to show several types of dates depending on the actual day and time.
But I do not want to change the output once generated.

So for example in box 1:

Now its "21.01.2017 13:38", the output should be "21.01.2017 11:28", but now the time should stay "21.01.2017 11:28", even when the actual time changes to 13:39. So once generated, it should not change (as long as I do not reload the page for sure).

Is moment.js the best solution for this or how can I do it?

I prepared a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/0wv8w62h/1/

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 2 hours and 10 minutes
  </span>
  <span class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 2 days
  </span>
  <span class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 12 days
  </span>
  <span class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY</span>
</div>
```

My JS skills are still pretty low, so I don't know, how to use e.g. moment.js and display the output in the boxes.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use moment [`subtract`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/):

> Mutates the original moment by subtracting time.

Using [`moment()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/) you get the current time, then you can subtract the unit of time that you need (2 hours and 10 minutes, 12 days etc). You can get the value of a moment object using [`format()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/).

Here a live sample using jQuery [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/):

```js
var solutions = $('.solution');
$(solutions[0]).html(moment().subtract({h: 2, m: 10}).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'));
$(solutions[1]).html(moment().subtract(2, 'd').format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
$(solutions[2]).html(moment().subtract(12, 'd').format('DD.MM.YYYY'));
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.whatshouldhappen {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: arial;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 2 hours and 10 minutes
  </span>
  <span class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 2 days
  </span>
  <span class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 12 days
  </span>
  <span class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little verbose but here is a JS fiddle that should achieve what I think your goal is.
https://jsfiddle.net/0wv8w62h/2/

In summary it add's ID's to the elements where the time would go so we can select them easily in JavaScript

```
<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 2 hours and 10 minutes
  </span>
  <span id="timeOne" class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY HH:MM</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 2 days
  </span>
  <span id="timeTwo" class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY</span>
</div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="whatshouldhappen">
    Date now minus 12 days
  </span>
  <span id="timeThree" class="solution">DD.MM.YYYY</span>
</div>
```

And then we have some JavaScript that 
 1. Gets the current date time 
 2. Gets each of the target elements to display the date values
 3. Calculates the new date for the target field, sets the text in the HTML element to the target format. There are more elegant ways to do this, but for the sake of simplicity I have posted this solution

```
var MILLISECONDS_IN_MINUTE = 1000 * 60;
var MILLISECONDS_IN_HOUR = MILLISECONDS_IN_MINUTE * 60;
var MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY = MILLISECONDS_IN_HOUR * 24;
var timeNow = new Date();

var timeOneElement = document.getElementById("timeOne");
if (timeOneElement) {
    var timeTwoHoursTenMinutesEarlier = new Date(timeNow.getTime() - (MILLISECONDS_IN_HOUR * 2) - (MILLISECONDS_IN_MINUTE * 10));
    timeOneElement.innerText = formatDate(timeTwoHoursTenMinutesEarlier) + " " + formatTime(timeTwoHoursTenMinutesEarlier);
}

var timeTwoElement = document.getElementById("timeTwo");
if (timeTwoElement) {
    var timeTwoDaysEarlier = new Date(timeNow.getTime() - (MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY * 2));
    timeTwoElement.innerText = formatDate(timeTwoDaysEarlier);
}

var timeThreeElement = document.getElementById("timeThree");
if (timeThreeElement) {
    var timeTwelveDaysEarlier = new Date(timeNow.getTime() - (MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY * 12));
    timeThreeElement.innerText = formatDate(timeTwelveDaysEarlier);
}

function formatDate(date) {
    return padZero(date.getDate()) + "." + padZero(date.getMonth() + 1) + "." + date.getFullYear();
}

function formatTime(date) {
    return padZero(date.getHours()) + ":" + padZero(date.getMinutes());
}

function padZero(value) {
    return (value < 10 ? "0" : "") + value
}
```